# Remove Event Listener from Checkbox Using Input Type?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

So I have this simple event listener that updates my price when I click on a checkbox.

However, I don't see how I can refactor my logic to make it subtract the price after unchecking a check box?

```
let items = 0;

document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches("input[type=checkbox]")) {
    items += +e.target.value;
    console.log(items);

    document.getElementById("price").textContent = `Food Total: $${(
      items / 100
    ).toFixed(2)}`;
  }
});
```

So far this code adds all my checkboxes values, but if I continue to click and unclick them, they still add the value to infinity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd add the checked boxes to a Set and add/delete them from the Set on click. Check whether they're already in the set to determine whether you need to add or subtract from the sum.

```
const clickedCheckboxes = new Set();
let sum = 0;
const priceDiv = document.getElementById("price");
document.addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => {
    if (!target.matches("input[type=checkbox]")) {
        return;
    }
    if (clickedCheckboxes.has(target)) {
        clickedCheckboxes.delete(target);
        sum -= target.value;
    } else {
        clickedCheckboxes.add(target);
        sum += Number(target.value);
    }
    priceDiv.textContent = `Food Total: $${(sum / 100).toFixed(2)}`;
});
```

Comment: what is new Set() in this example?

Comment: A Set is a built-in data structure that represents a collection of values (which can be anything, including HTMLElements). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: and you used const for priceDiv? wouldn't let make sense since the price is changing based on the checkboxes checked?

Comment: No, `const` indicates that the variable is not reassigned. It does not indicate anything about whether the value the variable points to is mutated or not. Because the price element is never reassigned to something else, best to declare it with `const` - it makes code more readable when you can know at a glance whether a variable name might be reassigned later.

Comment: ah okay and what is the word new mean in the function? I didn't see it on the set() docs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript `new` is the way to construct an instance from a class

Comment: is there a way to write it without using constructors?

Comment: Sure, there are almost always other ways, but there's absolutely nothing wrong with using Sets, they're what I prefer

Comment: if you replaces set() with something else, how would you refactor it? because I never seen set before and want to see if its possible to do with simple if else statements

Comment: I guess you could add the elements to an array instead and use `.includes`, or add the input names instead of the inputs (if they're different) or toggle a class instead, but I don't see a point in refactoring to something else

Comment: I was researching on set an apparently it doesn't count duplicate values? so that seems conflicting if I am creating a food app and items have the same price?

Comment: The approach in my answer should count duplicate values fine; one HTMLElement in the Set will not be considered to be the same as another such element. If you're using the input names instead, make sure to give each input a separate name, else duplicate names will mess things up.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a class "checked" when clicking the checkbox and remove it when clicking again? Then you could work with the class instead of the raw click event.

Comment: that just seems like so much extra code for such a simple thing

Answer (score 0):

I think checkboxes should have a simple boolean value of .checked being either true or false: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp

That might allow you to decrement if .checked === false

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).